# Accessing array data in object? Processing

Tags: java, arrays, csv, processing

Quite new to processing and hoping for some help! I'm trying to pull some data from a CSV file (that I will be manually entering values into, each row contains a name in the first column, then topics in subsequent columns, varying per row). I'm then trying to create circles with a radius based on how many topics are next to each name (so bigger circles for names with more topics). Here's what I have so far (needs lots of tidying but almost works):

```java
Circle[] circles = new Circle[3];

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(255);

  String lines[] = loadStrings("data.csv");
  String [][] csv;
  int csvWidth=0;

  //calculate max width of csv file
  for (int i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String [] chars=split(lines[i], ',');
    if (chars.length>csvWidth) {
      csvWidth=chars.length;
    }
  }

  //create csv array based on # of rows and columns in csv file
  csv = new String [lines.length][csvWidth];

  //parse values into 2d array
  for (int i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String [] temp = new String [lines.length];
    temp= split(lines[i], ',');
    for (int j=0; j < temp.length; j++) {
      csv[i][j]=temp[j];
    }
  }
  //test
  println(csv[2]);

  for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i] = new Circle(csv[i]);
    circles[i].display();
  }
}


class Circle {
  String[] array;

  Circle(String[] tempArray) {
    array = tempArray;
  }
  void display() {
    int diam = array.length-1;
    println(diam);
    String name = array[0];
    println(name);
    float x = random(0, width);
    float y = random(0, height);

    fill(0+(diam*40));
    ellipseMode(CENTER);

    ellipse(x, y, diam*20, diam*20);
    fill(0);
    text(name, x-((diam*20)/2), y+(diam*14));
  }
}
```

The problem I'm getting is that the diameters of the circles are all the same, even though the names change correctly. I know my logic must be way off, but my brain is melting from Googling this all day!

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Also, had it working fine by manually adding new objects, but thought it would be tidier/faster (though proving not to be the case) to import from a CSV?

```java
Circle myCircle1;
Circle myCircle2;
String[] circle1 = {"john smith", "processing", "video", "motion"};
String[] circle2 = {"betty mcd", "processing", "video", "motion","pizza","design"};

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(255);
  myCircle1 = new Circle(circle1);
  myCircle1.display();
  myCircle2 = new Circle(circle2);
  myCircle2.display();

}

void draw() {
}

class Circle {
  String[] array;

  Circle(String[] tempArray) {
    array = tempArray;
  }
  void display() {
    int diam = array.length-1;
    println(diam);
    String name = array[0];
    println(name);
    float x = random(0, width);
    float y = random(0, height);

    fill(0+(diam*40));
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(x, y, diam*20, diam*20);
    fill(0);
    text(name, x-((diam*20)/2), y+(diam+50));
  }
}
```

Comment: a few time i didnt work with Processing, i didnt know they are un 2.1.1 version.... for your problem, what is your version? loadStrings function only work with 2+ versions...

Comment: @kraysak if you look at the 1.5.1 documentation, you'll see that `loadStrings()` was included before the 2.x series.

Comment: ohh you are right, i didnt read very well the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```java
  csv = new String [lines.length][csvWidth];
```

You make all the rows in your table the same length, which is the maximum number of terms in the csv. Then, when you do this:

```java
void display() {
int diam = array.length-1;
```

All circles have an array of that same maximum length (not all of them will have *full* arrays, mind you; they will have the data you intended, and then a bunch of nulls afterwards). This is because of this code:

```java
for (int j=0; j < temp.length; j++) {
   csv[i][j]=temp[j];
}
```

The array `csv[i]` already has a bunch of preallocated memory from before, so you only overwrite the first few elements of it. The rest of the array still exists, and so when you call `array.length`, it returns the length of the array (including the extra nulls), not just your data. To be clear, here's an example: say that your `csvWidth` is five and there are three lines in your file, like so:

```
one,two,three
one,two,three,four,five
one,two
```

So the max length is five and the number of lines is three. `csv = new String [lines.length][csvWidth];` will then result in something like this:

```java
{{null,null,null,null,null},
 {null,null,null,null,null},
 {null,null,null,null,null}}
```

When you copy the file contents into your table, you get this:

```java
{{"one","two","three",null,null},
 {"one","two","three","four","five"},
 {"one","two",null,null,null}}
```

The length of each row remains five, even though your data only take up a fraction of it in most cases. There are a couple ways to fix this: you could make it so that each row in your `csv` table has a variable length, which would be the best solution; or you could have code in the `Circle` class that determines how many useful elements are in its array and determines diameter like that.

Comment: Also, thanks for writing such a thought-out and complete question!

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense! Thanks very much for helping me visualize that. I understand what I need to do... yet another day has passed and I haven't figured it out. The code for calculating the width of the CSV and csv array were one of those copy & paste without fully realizing what it was doing, unfortunately.

Comment: Glad to help out! If you're stuck implementing a solution, post another question with what you've tried and where you got stuck. Also, don't forget to upvote and accept answers if they were helpful :)